# Сохранить DSA ключ

Tags: java, android

Генерирую вот таким образом приватный и публичный ключ для цифровой подписи алгоритмом `DSA`.

```
Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256WithDSA");
SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DSA");
KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
//signature.initSign(keyPair.getPrivate(), secureRandom);
String pub = Base64.encodeToString(keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT);
String priv = Base64.encodeToString(keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Закодировал данную строку в формат `base64`. Подразумевается, что я смогу передать данные ключи другому приложению, где из `base64` строки я верну приватный и публичный ключ.

Подскажите как можно преобразовать переменную `pub` обратно в публичный ключ? Или может есть более удачное решение для хранения и передачи ключей?

Answer (score 0):

Так:

```
public static PublicKey getKey(String base64encoded){
    try{
        byte[] byteKey = Base64.decode(base64encoded.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(byteKey);
        KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("DSA");
        return factory.generatePublic(keySpec);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```